# What is the best language to use for coding a bot for Disord?

Tags: bots, discord

I do not have experience with any particular language, but I wish to create a fetching Bot for my discord server.

I want people on my server to be able to type: !CharacterName, and have a bot respond with that character's stats and attributes.

What is the best coding language to use for the creation of such a bot, and do you know of any tutorials for it?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your experiences here will be greatly improved if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with what is (and is not) proper to ask about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just starting out I'd highly recommend Python for this.
Python is a really wonderfully easy language to pick up, and lends itself
really well to this kind of application.

https://www.python.org/

If you google "python discord bot" there are a fair few resources there.

Good luck, and I hope this is beginning of a much bigger journey for you.